# como detener(Pausar) video Embed al clickear otro botón

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo algo asi como varios Botones y varios videos embed que estan en una misma pagina algo parecido a como esta abajo

El problema aqui es que cuando presiono el botón siguiente para ver el otro tipo de reproductor , entonces aun siguen reproduciéndose a pesar de que clickeo otro button

```
<div class="option">
            <button  id="btn-option-1">Option 1</button>
            <button onclick="stopVideo()"  id="btn-option-2">Option 2</button>
            <button  id="btn-option-3">Option 3</button>
            <button  id="btn-option-4">Option 4</button>
        </div>


        <div class="IFR">
            <div  id="option-primera" class="contenedor">
                <script src="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/players/a6hX7axA-daN5ROI3.js"></script>
            </div>

            <div id="option-segunda" class="contenedor" style="display: none;" >

                <iframe src="https://mega.nz/embed/ojxllTRZ#f7Za-WcHB7TZ11Wdz34sPZHoM04C9vGQLltl-v9fn3Y" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
            </div>

            <div id="option-tercera" class="contenedor" style="display: none;" >

                <iframe src="https://easyload.io/e/DANAYq6qN1/DB_Ztrailer_mp4"   allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>

            <div id="option-cuarta" class="contenedor" style="display:none;" >

                <iframe src="https://jawcloud.co/embed-a92cujfqe8vs.html"  allowfullscreen></iframe>

            </div>

        </div>
```

he intentado con esto para ver si podia detener un video, pero no lo conseguí

```
<script>
     var video = document.getElementById("option-primera");
     function stopVideo(){
          video.pause();
          video.currentTime = 0;
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usas iframe no estas cargando solo el vídeo por eso no puedes hacer un video.pause(); porque no lo va a reconocer como si fuera un video.
NOTA: Iframe lo que carga es todo el html de la pagina que le pasas por src

Estas son las soluciones que conozco

1. Mirar si disponen de una api para que puedas trabajar con ella por
   ejemplo: https://easyload.io/api
2. Seria acceder o por javascript o por jquery a los elementos que
   funcionan con play y pause y modificarlos dentro del iframe y
   modificarlos  Te dejo un ejemplo con la documentación
   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, leeré la documentación, de todos modos si alguien puede comentar un ejemplo seria bueno